# Let $k$ be a real number. Prove that if the equation $|x^{2} - 3x| = x-2+k$ has two distinct roots, then either $-1 < k < 2$ or $k > 3$?

Tags: quadratics

The title is the problem.

The condition "has two distinct roots" is ambiguous, but I assume it to be ``having exactly two distinct roots".

Comment: it can't have more than $2$

Comment: This is false. Take $k=3$; then it has roots at $1,2\pm \sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the number of real roots as $k$ varies:
$$
\begin{cases}
0,&k<-1\\
1,&k=-1\\
2,& -1<k<2\\
3,& k=2\\
4,& 2<k<3\\
3,& k=3\\
2,& k>3
\end{cases}
$$

To see why, plot $|x^2-3x|-x+2$:

[image: Plot of |x^2-3x|-x+2]

Then the number of real roots for a given $k$ corresponds to the number of points in the horizontal slice at height $k$ of this graph.

For a formal proof, you can split up into cases based on if $x\in [0,3]$ or not; then the equation splits up into two quadratic equations.

Comment: Would you like to give a sketch of the formal proof?

Comment: Yes, you just adapt the picture! First show that $|x^2-2x|-x+2$ has minimum at $3$ (by splitting into cases, and using the minimum of a quadratic function). This shows that when $k\leq -1$, there is at most 1 solution. All that remains is to consider $k\in [2,3]$. So we intersect with each of the two quadratics in turn, and find that they both have 2 solutions. You can use a continuity argument as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Graph $y_1 = |x^2-3x|$, and $y_2 = x+c$. Then see from the graphs what values of $c$ then $k-2$ yields two different intersections.